# How to create a connection to Azure data lake storage to API?

Tags: c#, azure, api, azure-functions, azure-data-lake

We cannot find the script or code to the internet or anything that can connect to azure data lake storage. So we can retrieve data from azure data lake to API.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-dotnet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake` package to work with directories and files in ADLS2.

Install the Azure Storage Files Data Lake client library for .NET with NuGet by using the below command:

`dotnet add package Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake --version 12.0.0-preview.9`

This package allows you to interact with directories and files in the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 containers. You can create, remove, rename, directories and files. Uploading, downloading, appending is also possible. You can also get metadata of the files.

Please visit this [Microsoft official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.files.datalake-readme?view=azure-dotnet) to use the given sample codes which you can modify as per your ADLS account details.